# How does one find the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{3} +\sqrt[5]{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an algorithm that would work for any zero of a polynomial. $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}$ is simple ($\sqrt[3]{x}-6x-6=0$). is simple but anything more complicated that this seems almost like trial and error.

Comment: Small nitpick- $\sqrt[3]{x}-6x-6$ is not a polynomial. Also, the minimal polynomial is huge: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%283%29%2B3%5E1%2F3%2B3%5E1%2F5

Comment: Please use MathJax; e.g., `$2^{1/3} + 4^{1/3}$` yields $2^{1/3} + 4^{1/3}$.

Comment: How do you know it's the zero of a polynomial if you don't know a polynomial that it satisfies? (I suspect you are asking about a smaller class of numbers)

Comment: One way would be to consider the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[30]{3})$ and look at the linear map $f : x\mapsto (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[5]{3})x$. We can represent this this map by a matrix with respect to the power basis and thus calculate its characteristic/minimal polynomial which will then annihilate the element.

Comment: @leoli1, that's the systematic approach, which I favor. Unfortunately, the matrix is $30 \times 30$ and probably cannot be done by hand. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B3%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3%7D+%2B%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7B3%7D) can do it of course; it's not pretty but has degree $30$ as expected.

Comment: Are you interested in the specific example you give, or in a more general setting? For example, are you interested specifically in the sum of some numbers you *do* know the minimal polynomial for? If so, [the Resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) might be useful to you.

Comment: A more general setting. Thanks for replying.